# Designing a rental house booking system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I am developing a website for vacation home rentals, and I would like some help with the design of the object model.

I have the houses model, the users model, and now I am going to design and build the reservations model, which would have start and end date fields, user field, and a house field.

The booking process has several actions involved, choosing the house, choosing the dates, and finally making the payment. How would I develop the booking process so the reservation isn't saved until all these actions have been done? Is it a would idea to create a different model (ReservationRequest, for example) to handle the two states of the reservation? Otherwise, how can I handle the two states of a reservation?

Sorry if it this is a vague question, but any guidance for this kind of process will be very useful to me.

Comment: I'd question the premise of your the idea that you don't save the reservation until the reservation is complete.  You can simply have a state associated with the reservation that would be set to "complete" once you've finished all of the actions associated with the reservation.  You can then create named scopes within your model to grab "complete" reservations.  There's nothing wrong with storing incomplete reservations in your database - you can periodically purge them if you need to, and you may actually get some useful analytics out of the state of incomplete reservations.

Comment: That's a really good idea, I didn't consider it before. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered the problem of check availability in that range of days? If you just receive reservation requests it's not a problem but if you make the user pay it could be a problem

Comment: @Aldo yes, I've got that covered. My only concern is how to handle the reservation pre and post payment. I am writing lots of tests for every use case I can think so there shouldnt be any surprises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your policy. I wouldn't store anything server-side until a valid payment is initiated. This way users can't block houses and then change their minds. I'd pass objects (houses and dates)  back and forth between different pages of the wizard. When a payment is initiated I'd store the Reservation in the database - so assuming an optimistic point of view - and this would lock the House. If then the payment fails, destroy the Reservation and send appropriate messages (emails). This way everyone can restart the whole process. But this really depends on how many users there will be and how concurrent is the environment

Comment: Many users still use _bank tranfer_ as payment method.With bank trasfer you need few days to get the money, I don't think is a great problem if an house is locked for few days while the money arrive.
If it's a problem probably you can use this approach but consider "old way" users are left out.

Comment: Sorry, the last sentence it should be "if it's _not_ a problem you can use this approach [...]"